# How to implement "cleos push action" in Node.js via RPC or eosjs?

Tags: cleos, eosjs, rpc

I'm working on Todos example in the following link. 
[To Do list smart contract](https://www.eosdocs.io/dappdevelopment/datastorage/)

By using cleos utility, everything works fine.

Now, I'm trying to access the smart contract with Node.js RPC.

How can I implement the following functionalities with Node.js RPC?

$ cleos --wallet-url http://172.18.0.1:8899 -u http://172.18.0.1:8888 push action shlee create '["shlee", 2, "feed dog"]' -p shlee

Basically, I'd like to know how to implement push action command of cleos utility.

Will the following API work?

http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/push_block

Comment: You can do this via eosjs which is more proffered than RPC calls. If you really  want to do it via rpc call please explore push_transaction it requires a packed_transaction

Answer (score 2):

Here is my final code that is working ...

Thank you  leettamna

```
const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError, JsSignatureProvider } = require('eosjs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');                            // node only; not needed in browsers
const { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } = require('text-encoding');  // node, IE11 and IE Edge Browsers

const defaultPrivateKey = "5JUKRhWkNobtgSJSamcY2Yz4dpbAzZ3euTYK2d7rWUP118xyRiG"; // user shlee
const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);

const rpc = new JsonRpc(' http://172.18.0.1:8888', { fetch });

const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });

try {
(async () => {
  const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'shlee',
      name: 'create',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'shlee',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        author: 'shlee',
        id: 4,
        description: "feed dog",
      },
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  console.log(result);
})();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + e);
  if (e instanceof RpcError)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 'eosjs'.

It is official javascript eos rpc library.

repository has simple example.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs

modify defaultPrivateKey = "shlee_private_key",
and parameter1 ~ parameter3 to correct parameter name
and http://127.0.0.1:8000 to your node api endpoint

```
const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError, JsSignatureProvider } = require('eosjs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');                            // node only; not needed in browsers
const { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } = require('text-encoding');  // node, IE11 and IE Edge Browsers

const defaultPrivateKey = "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr"; // useraaaaaaaa
const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);

const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://127.0.0.1:8000', { fetch });

(async () => {
  const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'shlee',
      name: 'create',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'shlee',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        parameter1_name: 'shlee',
        parameter2_name: 2,
        parameter3_name: "feed dog",
      },
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  console.dir(result);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot.  I appreciate that you wrote the actual code for me. One more question, cleos command uses --wallet-url http://172.18.0.1:8899 option. I guess that this option is used to retrieve the private key of the user. So I need to retrieve the private key from the keosd and then run the code you wrote. Is that correct?

Comment: in above code, key is privided directly. look at JsSignatureProvider code. :)      in this case keosd is not used.

Comment: const defaultPrivateKey = "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr";
      <- you have to input shlee's private key here.

Comment: Right. I understand your code. But I'd like to mimic what cleos do. Based on your code and the cloes command that I mention, it seems that cloes retrieves the private key of shlee from the keosd in 172.18.0.1:8899 (--wallet-url 172.18.0.1:8899 option)  and contacts the nodeos to push the action with the retrieved private key..  By doing so, I can avoid to put the private key in the code...

Comment: We can put the private key to encrypted DB and load it when needed. i think . :)